# ajax response and html not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here I am trying to get result in jsp page using ajax but i am getting improper result.

Problem: My ajax response is displayed first instead of my table headings. That means it should show table headings and then table content but not happening.

[my jsp page displaying result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHY70.png)

My Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $('#form1').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var post_url = form.attr('action');
                var post_data = form.serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: post_url,
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(msg) {

                        console.log(msg);
                        $('#LogsReceived').append(msg);

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="result" >

<p>
<table>

    <div id="LogsReceived">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Severity</th>
            <th>Source Host</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Program</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Facility</th>
            <th>Event Time</th>
        </tr>

    </div>
</table>
</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is invalid. You can't have a `div` as a direct child of `table` and as a parent of `tr`. What you're looking for there is `thead` or `tbody`, not `div`. It's being corrected by the browser, relocating the `div` to *before* the table. (Because it's invalid, the browser can do anything it wants: Put the `div` before, put it after, treat it as though it were a `tbody`, ...) Putting a `table` in a `p` is similarly invalid. You can see the rearrangement with the dev tools of your browser: Just right-click the table headers and choose "Inspect element" (or similar):

[image]

I recommend reviewing the various rules for what elements can go where in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-3).

Probably, you want both `thead` and `tbody`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Severity</th>
            <th>Source Host</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Program</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Facility</th>
            <th>Event Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="LogsReceived">
    </tbody>
</table>
```